# What is C-3PO's allegiance at the start of Rebels?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels, c-3po

In C-3PO's first appearance on Star Wars Rebels, he initially appears to be a true blue Imperial while R2-D2 is in on Bail Organa's Rebel activities. C-3PO even sent a distress signal to the Empire for rescue.

At the end of the episode, however, Bail Organa asked if C-3PO had revealed Bail's identity, suggesting C-3PO may be in on the act...or not.

So which is it? Does C-3PO identify himself as an Imperial senatorial protocol droid or a Rebel in disguise?

Comment: Given the canon quote from the official webpage, I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 9):

At the point that he calls the Empire for assistance, C-3PO has no indication that the crew of the Ghost are anything more than common criminals, out to kidnap droids and steal guns:

> **C-3PO:** *My counterpart and I were abducted from the spaceport on Garel by criminals. Thieves! OUTLAWS!*

As you've noted, the ending shows C-3PO is clearly well aware that he needs to be discreet about his Master's identity but there's no good reason he shouldn't call for Imperial help if he thinks he's been kidnapped since his owner is hiding behind the guise of being a super-loyal Senator.

The [Disney facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/starwarsrebels/photos/a.230754950414469.1073741828.180356405454324/367716480051648/) for the episode also strongly indicates that C-3PO is clueless about his master's rebellious activities:

> On loan to the Empire and serving as a translator, **C-3PO is an
>   *unknowing* accomplice in R2-D2's secret assignment.**

Comment: Personally, I wonder what in-universe sense keeping Jar Jar and C3P0 around makes...

Comment: @thegreatjedi - C-3PO is a protocol droid. For the vast majority of the show, we see conflict between ambassadors and leaders of nations. It makes excellent sense to have appropriate servants. Jar Jar, on the other hand seems to be little more than comic relief. Eventually they wrote him out entirely.